# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't display font correctly

Tags: windows, fonts, visual-studio

I'm using Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64 on my computer, and I'm also using Visual Studio 2013 Premium. For some reason, VS won't display/render the font that I want to use correctly. I'm trying to use [Inconsolata-dz](http://nodnod.net/2009/feb/12/adding-straight-single-and-double-quotes-inconsola/). Examples are below--the thing I've noticed so far is that the bottom line in `=` is not shown. Other characters may be messed up as well, but I haven't noticed anything. How do I fix this problem? (I read that many people had/have issues with ClearType; the problem exists for me whether ClearType is on or off.)

This is what the font looks like when the window opens before I install it:

[image: correct, when installing font]

This is what the font looks like in Notepad++, also correct:

[image: correct, N++]

Finally, this is how that exact same text displays in VS13. (Yes, I have VS13 set to a smaller font size, but the problem still occurs when the font is larger, and I don't code with a larger font anyway.)

[image: incorrect, VS13]

Comment: Does this happen with the original Inconsolata too? How about other third-party fonts?

Comment: @Karan Just checked--the problem happens with Inconsolata-dz, as originally mentioned, as well as [Inconsolata-g](https://leonardo-m.livejournal.com/77079.html). It *does not* happen with the [original Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) or with [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro).

Comment: So clearly whatever edits were made messed up the font somehow.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue with many different fonts: Monoid, Inconsolata-g,  and various others. Often these fonts look better a very high points in Visual Studio, but to the extent that the letters are too big for me to work with on my monitor - I don't see enough words for my liking.